# Firebase user authentication in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to acsess data on firebase from python (2.7).

Here are my rules (on firebseio.com):

```
{
    "rules": {
        "user": {
          "$uid": {
            ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
            ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my databse:

[image]

And last, my python code:

```
from firebase import firebase
from firebase.firebase import FirebaseApplication, FirebaseAuthentication

DSN = 'https://<my name>.localhost'
EMAIL = 'qqq@qqq.qqq'
authentication = FirebaseAuthentication(EMAIL, True, True, extra={'id': '<the user id>'})
firebase = FirebaseApplication(DSN, authentication)
firebase.authentication = authentication
print authentication.extra

user = authentication.get_user()
print user.firebase_auth_token
```

Now I cant figer out how to get data and send data to and from firebase.
I tryed useing the line: `result = firebase.get('/users', None, {'print': 'pretty'})`, But it gives me this error:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<my name>.localhost', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /users/.json?print=pretty&auth=<the token code of the user> (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x02A913B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))
```

Can Anyone provide me with a working code?

Thanks in advance,

Zvi Karp

Comment: What if Im not using a DSN?

Answer (score 7):

Here are the steps we took to get authentication working.

(1) First you need a Firebase Secret. 
After you have a project in Firebase, then click Settings. Then click Database and choose to create a secret.  [image: settings]

Copy your secret. It will go into your code later.

[image: secret]

(2) You need your firebase URL. 
It will have the format like this: https://.firebaseio.com
Copy this too.

(3) Get a Firebase REST API for Python. 
We used this one: https://github.com/benletchford/python-firebase-gae
Navigate to above your lib directory and run this command which will place the firebase code into your lib directory:

```
git clone http://github.com/benletchford/python-firebase-gae lib/firebase
```

(4) In your "main.py" file (or whatever you are using) add this code:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')

from firebase.wrapper import Firebase

FIREBASE_SECRET = 'YOUR SECRET FROM PREVIOUS STEPS'
FIREBASE_URL = 'https://[…].firebaseio.com/'
```

(5) Add this code to the MainHandler (assuming you are using AppEngine):

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        fb = Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users.json', FIREBASE_SECRET)

        new_user_key = fb.post({
            "job_title": "web developer",
            "name": "john smith",
        })
        self.response.write(new_user_key)
        self.response.write('<br />')

        new_user_key = fb.post({
            "job_title": "wizard",
            "name": "harry potter",
        })
        self.response.write(new_user_key)
        self.response.write('<br />')

        fb = Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users/%s.json' % (new_user_key['name'], ), FIREBASE_SECRET)
        fb.patch({
            "job_title": "super wizard",
            "foo": "bar",
        })

        fb = Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users.json', FIREBASE_SECRET)
        self.response.write(fb.get())
        self.response.write('<br />')
```

Now when you navigate to your Firebase Realtime Database, you should see entries for Harry Potter as a user and others.